# Remove Human Verification on trusted users

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Human Verification is basically intended to be a less invasive CAPTCHA, only appearing if you are determined to maybe be a robot according to some arbitrary rules.

But surely someone with many thousands of reputation points should be trusted enough to be human?

I don't really understand why it is necessary to still have to jump through this hoop every few answers even after being around for so long and contributing so much. I even had a desktop game sent to me by the SO team, surely that's proof enough that I'm human! :p

In short: Remove Human Verification for users with sufficiently high* reputation.
<sub>* I would suggest 1,000, as part of the "Established User" privilege</sub>

Comment: 1k?  5k.  1k is too low.

Comment: That's why I put the 1k suggestion as a footnote, and left the actual suggestion vague ;)

Comment: Vague suggestions aren't desirable, but I see contention on "sufficiently high".

Comment: Closely related: [I am not a robot!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143455), [Can I please be trusted to not to script a bot that dumps an endless stream of spam into chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132483), [Are captchas necessary for established users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143463)

Comment: I'd say maybe 5k. They're not really that annoying and don't pop up very often for me.

Comment: it would be a cool if rep limit would be like 2k .. since 2k user edit anything without permission(have lots of trust)

Comment: @random, I think this would be the better one to link to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing.