# An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA

Tags: bug, captcha

Even though I have an account and I am already logged in, I cannot post at [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

Stack Exchange has this annoying CAPTCHA. If I submit a wrong answer to the CAPTCHA, I get: "Oops! Those aren't the correct words", and if I submit a correct one, I get: "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA". The result is that I cannot post anything.

Besides, I have an old account with plenty enough reputation across the Stack Exchange network: I would have thought that the software would have known by now that this is not a spammer-operated account! Why is the CAPTCHA so intrusive on normal users?

Comment: Regarding reputation and captchas, read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143463/are-captchas-necessary-for-established-users

Comment: Including your system details would probably be helpful here.

Comment: Captchas are reduced at the higher rep levels, but not eliminated.  A compromised account with high rep combined with a bot can do a lot of damage.

Comment: I would check two things. First maybe your IP keep changing and second maybe you have some browser plugin/extension that cause lots of page loads.

Comment: Same thing happening to me on EE, very frustrating. Disabled everything (HTTPS Everywhere, Adblock, Ghostery, Noscript, firefox's own XSS protection...) and only ever get "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA" with no details or alternative.

Comment: Same thing happened to me on SO - I couldn't post an answer using Chrome, but Firefox let me without prompting me to enter a CAPTCHA!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can turn off JavaScript, and most Stack Exchanges will provide a non-JavaScript CAPTCHA to use. You may also see the fallacious message that Stack Exchange works best with JavaScript, which you can obviously ignore.