# Display fewer CAPTCHAs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

When a user with a deep compulsive obsessive disorder, like me, goes in a rampage fixing everybody's spelling, grammar and general style and code style errors, displaying a CAPTCHA every 3 or so submits doesn't do anything but deter that person from improving the general quality of the content at any Stack Exchange site.

I think less CAPTCHA should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There are already reduced captchas for users with 10k rep as documented here

[Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing/8036#8036)

Comment: I nearly crapped my pants when I saw a different image above the CAPTCHA today.

Comment: @TheTXI Agreed, it kind of startled me cause I thought I clicked the wrong link or it went to a new site when I saw the new image. ahhh!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why *any* CAPTCHA's are required for users in that range? What are they there to stop? No-one there is suddenly turning their account into a spambot. Seems a little odd.

Comment: Not intentionally. But your account may get hijacked.

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but you'd like to think there were ways to immediately suspend an account if it was noted that was occurring [i.e. via user reports]. Regardless, sure. No point arguing I guess.