# Can throttling be eliminated for users with a certain rep?

Tags: feature-request, throttling

I hate dealing with throttling of comments and edits. I like to write a quick answer, and then go back and edit it to be more detailed. However, I frequently have to type CAPTCHAs and wait. Is there any way users with a certain reputation(say 500) could be exempted from throttling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[10k+ users are already subject to reduced CAPTCHAs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing/8036#8036). Complete CAPTCHA elimination is not a good idea as your user account may be hijacked. Even Jeff is subject to the same threshold that we are (claimed in a podcast, not verified ;) ).

Comment: In some ways, the accounts with more power need additional checks *especially* to slow down the potential damage from hijacking.

Answer (score 4):

> I like to write a quick answer, and then go back and edit it to be more detailed.

And I think this is plain, bad behaviour. You are trying to be the first to answer a question, thus hoping to gain the most reputation. This is not okay in my opinion. You should give a full answer, not a quick answer. If it takes you a while to give a full answer then you need to learn to give shorter -but complete- answers.

If a simple one-liner provides a complete answer, fine. Post the one-liner. But if you just post a quick answer so your answer will be the first one, albeit incomplete, then that is considered bad behaviour...