# Are you a human being?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Captcha for higher rep users even necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/why-is-captcha-for-higher-rep-users-even-necessary)
>   [Please stop asking me a captcha with over 500 reputation. I am human](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81012/please-stop-asking-me-a-captcha-with-over-500-reputation-i-am-human)

The fact that you are asking me this question when I am LOGGED IN using my Google account is a very, very disturbing thing.

It suggests that your site and servers are a security nightmare, and that no one should entrust you with their personal information.

Comment: How does it suggest that? It is possible to login manually and then run a bot while you're still logged in, you know.

Comment: This happens after several edits are made consecutively, right?

Comment: The only thing it suggests is that you don't understand how these things work. A spammer could easily log in to their Google account, and then start a bot. The captcha mechanism is there to prevent that (very real) possibility.

Comment: Hmmm... ***are*** you a human being? (a bot would say surely say "yes", so answer carefully)

Comment: You're right on one part: _no one should entrust you with their personal information._ I don't know what kind of personal information you've been asked to give but here we just do programming...

Comment: [Nice try, robot.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60055/170332)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please stop asking me a captcha with over 500 reputation. I am human](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81012/please-stop-asking-me-a-captcha-with-over-500-reputation-i-am-human), [Why is Captcha for higher rep users even necessary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/why-is-captcha-for-higher-rep-users-even-necessary), [Can throttling be eliminated for users with a certain rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34248/can-throttling-be-eliminated-for-users-with-a-certain-rep)

Comment: No. No, I am not.

Answer (score 22):

It's a bot protection mechanism.  Bots can't solve the Captcha.  Occasionally it gets tripped by a human being exhibiting machine-like behaviors.  That has nothing to do with login security or personal information.

People can still do lots of damage with bots, even if they're logged in.  *Especially if they're logged in.*

Answer (score 13):

> The fact that you are asking me this question when I am LOGGED IN
>   using my Google account is a very, very disturbing thing.

Really? Can't a bot sign up with a Google account to and go off on a spamming rampage? Your argument isn't the best here, since anyone can get a Google ID and get a bot to sign in with it.

> It suggests that your site and servers are a security nightmare, and
>   that no one should entrust you with their personal information.

No, it suggests that we actually care about what content is being posted on this site and would like to avoid some bot posting "I LOVE PONIES" everywhere.

Comment: Aww... I liek ponies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We like [meta-tag:unicorns] here.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan: <3

Comment: lieking ponies is okay; LOVING ponies is not.  If I'm reading this correctly.

Answer (score 12):

> It suggests that your site and servers are a security nightmare, and that no one should entrust you with their personal information.

No, it suggests that we don't trust our users<sup>†</sup> (that they necessarily are human beings). Isn't that the pinnacle of security practices anyway?

---

<sub>† Not those with [under 20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) anyway.</sub>

Comment: I occasionally get the captcha even with 150k+ rep

Comment: @Pekka: Aw. I was hoping to be serious about that 20k privilege, but I guess not.

Comment: @Pekka we also show the captcha to people with "Bordello" in their name ;-)

Comment: Even a ♦ does not make one immune to the dreaded captcha.