# Human verification appears too much in the way when reorganizing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)

Make human verification appear less often in frequent editions for users with a certain rep.

Human verification appears every time I make two or three editions in a very short time. Sometimes I'm just retagging, like right now, from moderator-election to moderator-nomination.

It gets too much in the way. It effectively discourages me from making more useful edits.

---

**Update:** "status-completed". Well. I have 7,817 reputation points right now. I was going to retag four or five c# questions about var to add them the `var` tag. And the robots appeared again. I stop retagging every time I see the robots.

Comment: I run into this all the time.

Comment: I've very rarely seen this. Strange.

Comment: I get this all the time, too.

Comment: I believe this is already the case for 10k users. I haven't seen a captcha on SO in months.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing

Comment: While this is very close to a duplicate, the use case was different.

Comment: By the way, I saw it last _here_, on Meta. I am _very_ far from 10k in this particular site. Does this mean I can't edit four tags in a row without seeing this page turned into a capture from Zombieland.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree wholeheartedly.  I am getting quite annoyed, since I ask myself how often I will have to prove my humanity again.

What the system currently does is saying "Bad boy, don't edit so often" and "Bad boy, you took too long to edit".

Comment: My feeling is rather "Bad boy, you were too quick". I get it always when I make a quick edit.

Comment: +1 to your answer and +1 also to @Pekka's "too quick" comment. That's what happens to me all the time. And for meaningful editions, it may just be the same tag in four different questions so I can be really quick without messing up as the site is implying.

Answer (score 6):

[It's already in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing), just get to 10,000 reputation.

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the human-verification tag rather than the captcha tag. No wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, I am discussing about the usability of the site. And I will have used the site in the "low usability" mode and seen the PITA human veritifation page hundreds of times by the time I get to 10,000 - or, when I get tired of it, I will just stop tidying up the contents.

Comment: I do not understand why a user isn't considered "trust worthy" until 10,000 rep. I think that by the time you can edit questions(2000 rep) you should be considered trust worthy enough to not spam the site

Comment: @earlz There have been users that once they had edit powers spend a lot of time trying to re-organize the site to their liking. There is (rightfully) inertia against that.