# Tweak captcha logic in regard to errors

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, captcha, error-message

There have been at least two requests for a similar thing, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35722/human-verification-appears-too-much-in-the-way-when-reorganizing-closed) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing).

May I raise this question again, now in regard to submission errors.

Every now and then, I get an error when posting an answer or a question, like, the answer is too short, or I forgot to tag the question (I'm happy to get bugged about that, don't get me wrong). I quickly fix the error and submit again, at which point I every time have to face the captcha.

My suggestion: **Don't show the captcha for two consequtive submissions that are very close to each other, if the first submission resulted in an error, and the second submission doesn't cause an error**. If the second submission is wrong too, then no problem, show the captcha.

Comment: +1 quite annoying if you try to create a new tag at the SE-2.0 betas but don't have enough rep there

Comment: Agreed ... I just posted a dup question on this.

Answer (score 1):

My bug report was closed as a dupe of this, and while I'm not convinced it's exactly the same, it certainly touches the same logic, so I'm re-posting my specific report here:

> ### User action limits should take place before robot captchas
>
> New users with under 125 rep are not
>   allowed to post more often than every
>   3 minutes.
>
> However, when they press "submit" they
>   are not told this immediately, they
>   are whisked off for robot detection,
>   then rudely dumped back at their post
>   indicating that they must wait before
>   posting another item.
>
> The user limitations ought to be
>   tested prior to the robot test so the
>   user does not get the impression that
>   they are going to be successful as
>   long as they are not a robot.
>
> Honestly it's depressing enough to be
>   reminded that you are not an eternal
>   automaton without adding a heaping
>   spoonful of "you aren't good enough to
>   post this frequently anyway" on top of
>   that.

Comment: As it's not a dupe (ie, fixing this question's bug will not fix my question's bug) feel free to re-open my bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68201/user-action-limits-should-take-place-before-robot-captchas-closed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This will probably be a benefit to those of us who do lots of edits in a quick succession, but it was the problem desribed in the posts I'm [linking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35722/human-verification-appears-too-much-in-the-way-when-reorganizing-closed) [to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing) in my question. I was asking about a problem that is a bit different, and this new rule is not solving it at all, is it not?

Comment: I believe you've broken your captcha timer.  I'm getting it on every question I answer.