# User action limits should take place before robot captchas

Tags: bug, answers, new-users, captcha, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tweak captcha logic in regard to errors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60190/tweak-captcha-logic-in-regard-to-errors)

New users with under 125 rep are not allowed to post more often than every 3 minutes.

However, when they press "submit" they are not told this immediately, they are whisked off for robot detection, then rudely dumped back at their post indicating that they must wait before posting another item.

The user limitations ought to be tested prior to the robot test so the user does not get the impression that they are going to be successful as long as they are not a robot.

Honestly it's depressing enough to be reminded that you are not an eternal automaton without adding a heaping spoonful of "you aren't good enough to post this frequently anyway" on top of that.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question.  While it may touch on the same captcha/error logic, it is a separate issue.  In other words, fixing the other bug will not fix this one, and vice versa.  A single coding session may be able to take down both bugs simultaneously, but they aren't the same bug.