# Look again at increasing the captcha threshold for post editing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, captcha

This has been discussed [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing), and was actioned in a way that I can't help but feel is just wrong. This is why I've created a new question, given that the previous one has the 'status completed' tag.

I would like to see a better system for handling captcha throttle thresholds on users. Currently, according to [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood):

> Some reductions in CAPTCHA throttle
>   thresholds, if you have > 10k rep:
>
> - for edits -- reduced by two-thirds
> - for post submission times --
>     min seconds
>     reduced by one half, max minutes
>     increased by 2x

My point is that 10k reputation is **waaaaay** too high. As has been suggested, there should be some form of scaling involved in the threshold, rather than this system where editing/re-editing your posts confronts you with those damned loveable robots.

So, I would like to ask that you start scaling back the threshold when the user hits something lower, say 500, or 1000.

Comment: Or maybe 2500/5000? 500/1000 is all too easy to get. Once you start engaging with the site, the reputation can grow exponentially in a short term.

Comment: Well, I've been on the site (SO) for about a year, and my reputation is about 1800 and I've been no church mouse by any means!

Comment: I've been doubling my reputation every 2 months like clockwork. I've been expecting it to slow down but it doesn't... 3k->9k blew by in an instant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really a big deal to hit the captcha occasionally? It's like a surprise side encounter while on the main story mission.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's an annoyance that could/should be avoided as and when you build up reputation on the site. Think of it as another perk for being a good citizen. The threshold is simply too high. That's all. I'm asking for it to be lowered or scaled.

Comment: Unless you make a lot of mistakes like I do, and have to hit the captcha a lot.

Comment: Indeed. I make a few mistakes every now and again. Or I think of a better way to write an answer to a question, and end up refactoring it.