# Impossible Captcha with non-keyboard characters

Tags: discussion, captcha

Am I a human? Yes. Can I type *phi* off the top of my head? No. [image]

Comment: This is probably a bug. Urrgh what the what?

Comment: @Kristo and all - thanks. Maybe that's why... 8-\

Comment: Note that if you would have typed whatever you wanted instead, it probably would have worked as long as the first was "corrected".

Comment: How do we know that you're human unless you pass the CAPTCHA? Everyone be on your guard!! "Code Poet" is a human impersonator! He's trying to enlist your help to beat the CAPTCHA!

Comment: to add to Gnoupi's answer, SO uses re-captcha one of the words is known and one of the words is a scan from an old book.  By giving the captcha to many people, they can accurately determine the scanned words the computer can't recognize.  Effectively using small amounts of peoples time as powerful computer power to electronify books.

Comment: @Lumpy - if your comment had a checkmark next to it, it would be marked check.

Comment: As designed. A *robot* would not head off to meta, post this question, learn how to enter the CAPTCHA, then return to the page and complete the challenge. So clearly you are not a robot, and the CAPTCHA worked!

Comment: @Craig I don't know. That sounds exactly like a try - catch to me. `try { ReadCaptcha(); } Catch(InvalidCharacterException ex) { PostToMeta();RetrieveAnswerFromFoolishHumans();} Finally { SpamDeluge(); }`

Comment: Are we human? Or are we dancers?

Comment: I got this recently with a photon-symbol, and also one with chinese letters `><`

Comment: Related: TODAYS REVISIONS WTF?! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/48840/revisions

Comment: @Koning - i noticed that too. interesting..

Comment: As for revisions, I had my turn at it :)

Comment: Well for a moment, anyway.

Comment: @Koni I like @gnopi's the best. His "decap" version.

Comment: @Earlz: It removed the amateurish-ness of the question.

Comment: @George, @Jeff is about to come eat your soul for creating such tags.

Comment: @George, and you will be banned in 3....2....

Comment: @Earlz: So...? They're just as bad as your titles.

Comment: @George: ..1...0...-1...-2...

Comment: 24 hour ban. *makes note for answering questions later.

Comment: @earlz - i can live with that

Comment: Lol, I think we might have another Evan Carroll in the making...

Comment: @Aar I highly suspect this.

Comment: -3... -4... **BOOM!**  See you in a day, George.

Comment: (@Sky, the image is no longer on your server?)

Comment: Google uses recaptcha to digitalize copyrighted material. I do not understand why SO supports this and gives us no choice to use another captcha. See http://www.nytimes.com/2010/04/01/world/europe/01briefs-Francebrief.html?_r=1&ref=googlebooksearch for example.

Comment: You don't even need TeX. Just enter `ϕᴍ,ᴘ(x)` in plain text!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to reCAPTCHA:

> Each new word that cannot be read correctly by OCR is given to a user in conjunction with another word for which the answer is already known. The user is then asked to read both words. If they solve the one for which the answer is known, the system assumes their answer is correct for the new one.

So therefore if nobody else figured out this one, you would be the first and you could legitimately type anything and succeed at it.

Comment: So *that* would explain why it let me through when I accidentally mistyped a captcha...

Comment: Yeah, the policy is harass some internet users to get your work done for free...

Answer (score 57):

Pfft... that's easy. Try this one:

[image: worst captcha ever]

Comment: I smell a robot!

Comment: Burnt waffle reform. easy.

Comment: @Jon: I don't think that █ is an 'ARABIC PLACE OF SAJDAH' (U+06E9)

Comment: @Kenny: Ummm... they had an unfortunate fire?

Comment: Pretty easy on on iPhone `>++++++++++[>+++++++++++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++><<<<-]>>+>----><<<<>.>.>.`

Comment: Is it ▓ Reform?

Comment: It looks kind of like a cake.  Maybe it's "torte" reform.

Answer (score 37):

As promised, here's the one I got a few days ago:

[image]

**Edit:** One more from just now (looks like they are scanning math books):

[image]

Comment: ++ wtf indeed. .

Answer (score 31):

This is a trick question: you fail if you *can* type it.
The cat and mouse game continues...

Answer (score 27):

Remember that, if the challenge is too "hard" to solve, you can request a new one with the "refresh" button.

[image: Recaptcha and the "new challenge" button enclosed in a yellow freehand circle.]

Comment: Klaatu ampliti ni\*hack cough*!

Answer (score 23):

You misunderstood - you are supposed to solve the equation as well.
I know it's tough but we have to keep the cyborgs out of Meta.

Answer (score 23):

Readable, just confusing. It seems like reCAPTCHA is now digitising house numbers on Street View as well ;)

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Nice. And odd that they know where to find the number, but then still need a human to confirm its value ;-)

Comment: I've seen this recently. No else that I know agreed with me, about those being house numbers though. I am so happy that there is some else who believes that they are house numbers too!

Comment: Seriously dafuq!! o.O

Comment: Are there 2 *pi* before number?

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Now, isn't at least one of these supposed to be a real word?

Comment: Google: 'Your search - joutandt - did not match any documents'. lolz - what are the odds of 0 google hits on a single word consisting of ascii characters?

Comment: What's more impressive, we're discussing it on the Internet and it's __still__ a [Googlenope](http://googlenope.com/about.php)! (Also, I totally thought the second "word" was in Arabic at first.)

Comment: Clearly it's "joutandt OOMMG!!!"

Comment: No, "18 15 23 44" don't count as a word in my book, even if rotated by 90°.

Comment: @SkySanders Your comment is the top result, but nowadays there's also a Google Books results from something published in 1813...

Answer (score 18):

```
&phi;<sub>M,P</sub>(x)
```

φ<sub>M,P</sub>(x)

(or use LaTeX `\phi_{M,P}(x)`.)

Comment: &phi; doesn't work though :) it's clearly the capital letter Phi: ɸ. I am not sure of the HTML code for that though.

Comment: @Joshua: The capital Greek Phi (`&Phi;`) is Φ (U+03A6), not ɸ which is the Cyrillic Ef (U+0444). There's also a phi symbol ϕ (U+03D5) which may render like the image, depending on the font.

Comment: @Joshua: &phi; and &Phi; -> φ and Φ

Comment: You know, providing LaTeX equations in captchas would be excellent for http://mathoverflow.com to keep out the riff-raff. They're always complaining that they get too many elementary-level questions there... ;)

Answer (score 13):

I actually got 4 Greeks in a row. Sharing my favorite for posterity:

[image: adessurn ... aw crap.]

Answer (score 11):

First of all, I am human but no human being can decipher the ReCAPTCHA I just encountered.
[image]

Comment: Someone skipped differential calculus.

Comment: You only need to type "helects" for that

Comment: @YOU: Oh, there's no need for capitalization?

Comment: @Hendrik, Yeah, I used to type like that, and It works, IIRC.

Comment: What's so hard about `(\deltaa_i)/(\deltaa_(i-1))`?

Comment: @TomWijsman: It's `\partial a_i/\partial a_{i-1}` also pronounced "del", "dou", and other weird stuff. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110565/del-partial-delta-nabla-correct-enunciation/115253#115253

Comment: I guess so, that's over the top of my head...

Answer (score 9):

This is the best (or worst) CAPTCHA I've recieved.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's `\sum_(i=0)^n((-1)^n)/(2n-1^(\Delta^n)))`.

Comment: @TomWijsman: it's clearly (-1)^50 :)

Answer (score 6):

I just got one with an integral from -∞ to ∞. Is reCAPTCHA digitizing math books this week?

Comment: It's been for some time. I recall an integral from a few weeks ago.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if we're supposed to *solve* these?

Comment: @Bill: But there wasn't anything to integrate -- just the integral symbol. That's why it was so frustrating!

Answer (score 4):

I would have entered *ompx*.

You can also just press F5 to get another one.

Comment: Is that popular demand? Don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the symbol of diameter. Well... I can: ∅ and ϕ

This are some details of phi:

```
UTF-8: 0xCF 0x95
UTF-16: 0x03D5

C-form (octal escaped UTF-8): \317\225
XML-form (decimal): &#981;
```

[image: Symbols in linx]

Comment: Are you a human?

Comment: @code poet: Yes. In linux there is a very handy app that allows you to access all symbols.

Comment: NULL SET and PHI are not the same glyph.

Comment: @Quack Quixote: correct, the correct glyph is U+03D5 Greek Phi Symbol (referring to the posted image, it is the incorrect glyph). Windows also has a character lookup, called the Character Map.

Comment: Sadly, X's Alt Gr key mapping includes ø, but not phi.

Comment: @Mart: What app is that?

Answer (score -2):

*Distorted text CAPTCHAs can be a little stressful also!*

[image: Seriously!]

Comment: When did SE turn into reddit ?

Comment: *Must... Not... Type...*