# Captcha on AREA 51 is too hard for a human to solve

Tags: bug, area-51, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Today’s Captcha — wtf?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/todays-captcha-wtf)

Look at this Captcha I just got. Can someone turn down the difficulty of these..

[image: captcha]

Comment: Actually, if you just entered stears, you would've made it. Check out the reports at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/todays-captcha-wtf-closed for more details. Specifically, see George's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/todays-captcha-wtf/48870#48870).

Comment: That's a special CAPTCHA just for you.

Answer (score 74):

Nice try Robot.

Answer (score 69):

That's just (Φ,d)∈(X*\{0})×R, what's so difficult to enter?

(Seriously, you could just refresh to get a new one if you can't solve it.)

Comment: If using deliberately exposed features exactly as they are intended to be used is hacking, then I have 1337 skillz, d00d.