# Please stop asking me a captcha with over 500 reputation. I am human

Tags: support, captcha

I wonder how it is possible that Stack Overflow is still asking me to solve an unreadable [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) before I can post a question when I have more than five accounts on Stack Exchange, and I have more than 500 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wonder what triggers captcha in your case. In mine it's when it takes me more than 10-15 minutes in pressing submit

Comment: Probably for +100k :)

Comment: Does the reputation matter if your account is compromised?

Comment: I feel bad for you -- thus proving that I am a human -- but +1 to Arjan.

Comment: There's gonna be a captcha for as long as the true nature of Jon Skeet is undetermined. It could be a while.

Comment: Please don't smash your monitor, it is costly and may be a sign of some sort of illness. My new monitor now has 2 stuck pixels. Stuck pixels make me sad.

Comment: Actually, Jeff keeps the captcha around because he's afraid he's going to miss the singularity event, and he hopes that once programmers start transferring their minds to machines he'll be able to detect it and get in on it early.  Unfortunately most people agree the top 0.01% of stackoverflow have already reached that point, and the captcha isn't working.  *Jeff is worried.*

Comment: A likely argument for a robot to make.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't be seeing so many captchas, and if you are, something is wrong.

- Are you disabling or interfering with JavaScript? Any add-ins that would be interfering with JavaScript? Can you try your browser in safe mode (all defaults)?
- Can you try in another web browser?

Comment: Does the user's question/answer ratio matter? (This user has [73 questions, 29 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/496223/yes123), just 4 net-upvotes for the answers.)

Comment: @arjan no that does not matter

Comment: For what its worth, I get CAPTCHA often.  I just assumed it was because sometimes after insane amounts of caffeine I go on a SO binge and rapidly vote/reply/edit.  No complaints here though.  I understand that our nearly spam-free community comes at a slight inconvenience once in a while.

Answer (score 38):

I'll take my downvotes stoically, but couldn't resist:

[image]

Comment: It's pretty hard to get downvotes on Meta for posting a cartoon; even harder if it's Dilbert :)

Answer (score 15):

To quote [Pollyanna](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve/76000#76000):

> Nice try, robot.

Comment: Thanks for the attribution, but according to [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+"nice+try%2C+robot") I wasn't the [first to come up with that joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/captcha-on-area-51-is-too-hard-for-a-human-to-solve/60055#60055).

Comment: @Polly ah, good work! I, too, thought the original was made in response to Evan.

Comment: Poor robotic Evan.  He never did fit in, though it almost appears as though he attempted to appear as though he was almost trying to fit in.  But, you know.  Robots leave oil spots on the carpet, and I'm afraid that I'm a robotophobe.

Comment: There, I've linked mine to the original.  Now people can click from here to there, then to the original.  The next time a captcha question comes up, we'll add to the chain.  Eventually it will be long enough to *go around the world!*

Answer (score 10):

Okay, since you want a real answer and Arjan's comment wasn't good enough for you:

I see why you feel the way you do, but capping CAPTCHAs based on rep — or any other permanent solution — isn't the way to go. In theory, your account could be compromised and hooked up to a bot at any time. There are *some* limits, though. [According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing/8036#8036):

> Some reductions in CAPTCHA throttle thresholds, **if you have > 10k rep**:
>
> - for edits — reduced by two-thirds
> - for post submission times — minimum seconds halved, maximum minutes doubled
>
> CAPTCHAs are good for five minutes for logged-in users with ≥ 200 rep.

Comment: @Yes While it might not happen to *you*, it might happen to others. Just 5 compromised accounts is enough to spam the site for a while, which just because of probability is bound to happen

Comment: @yes123 The chances that it happens to _you_ are almost nonexistant. However, according to the birthday problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), there is a wild, wild possibility that it will happen to someone.

Comment: @zneak: you do not understand the birthday paradox AT ALL!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez As I understand it, the birthday paradox says that the chances of collisions between properties of any two entries of a set are stupid high, even though the chances of collisions of one precise element with any other one are fairly low.

Answer (score 9):

I'll play devil's advocate here:

The idea that you should be seeing fewer captchas because you have higher rep is backwards.  All that means is that there was a human behind the account at some point in the past.  However, it proves nothing about the present.  Your higher-rep account has more privilege, and therefore has a higher value to spammers.  Even if you don't have more privileges (say, accounts past 20K), you have more credibility.  If it's compromised, a spammer can do more with your account, and so it's precisely because of this rep that if anything we need to be more protective of these accounts.

Comment: Has a high reputation account ever been compromised?

Comment: Unless you count RichB, I don't know ;) - I'm just playing devil's advocate

Comment: @Tim, even Jeff's account [once got compromised](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html). (Now wondering if Jeff gets to see the captchas too!)

Comment: It's not just about spamming, but about scripted vandalism too.

Comment: @Arjan And Vandals Scripting Spam, and Spammers Vandalizing Scripts

Comment: When RichB touches a keyboard, the machine to which that keyboard is attached, has to be regarded as compromised.