# Why am I hitting the captcha for every answer I give (after installing new userscripts)?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, captcha, spam-detection

For the past couple days, I'm being forced through the captcha for every answer I give here on Meta and SO.

This sort of problem was brought up on Meta in the past couple months ([I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)), but 1) was only in the context of making quick edits (which haven't been a problem for me) and 2) was supposed to have been fixed.  I'm seeing the captcha every time I post an answer without any sort of activity that might involve rate-limiting.

What's going on?

---

**Update:**
Potential causes that **don't** appear to be the problem:

- **Answering too quickly and hitting rate limits.**
  When posting test answers that I purposely spend multiple minutes composing, I still get the captcha.
- **Captcha based on my shared IP.**
  An answer posted from an alternate account went through with no problem.

Comment: Are you within a company/school/university network? Might others be using SO from within the same network?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am on a shared connection at the office, but nothing's changed in that regard.  While possible that someone else here has started doing something to trip the limits, I have no reason to suspect that's the case.  Moreover, I thought that one of the purposes of having an account instead of anonymous use was more fine-grained limiting in the case of shared connections.

Comment: If you take too long or too short to post a message (e.g. copy paste/leave the PC for a while then come back and post) it seems to captcha you every time

Comment: @BenBrocka I just tried posting answers to the sandbox, purposely spending a full minute composing one and two minutes on the second, and still got the captcha.  Is the lower cutoff higher than that?

Comment: @blahdiblah that should be good. I'm wondering if David's right about it suspecting your IP for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81075/137004) from Jeff, I realized that the shiny new userscripts I installed recently might have something to do with the problem.  Testing revealed that the [WMD keyboard shortcut disabler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123256/137004) was the culprit.

Time to work on getting the same functionality without forcing me to constantly prove my humanity.

---

An updated Chrome user script based on Rob's (linked above):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Cya WMD shortcuts
// @namespace      Rob W
// @version        1.0
// @run-at         document-end
// @description   A hook to disable WMD keyboard shortcuts
// @match       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       http://superuser.com/*
// @match       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match       http://serverfault.com/*
// @match       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @match       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match       http://stackapps.com/*
// @match       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://chat.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude       http://*/reputation
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input').parentNode;
    function ignore(e){e.metaKey && e.stopPropagation();}    
    p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
    }()
);
```

Rather than eating all keyboard events, this only prevent Markdown from seeing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>whatever</kbd> events.

Comment: Better yet would be to install the event handler on `document` and check `e.target`.