# I am getting impossible captcha when trying to answer a question

Tags: discussion, captcha

I tried to answer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347610/closing-multiple-forms-in-c-sharp) and i keep getting impossible captcha like

[image: captcha]

I can't see anything. Pls I am not a bot or script but this captchas I have been getting after refreshing are quite Impossible.

Comment: Already answered the question, I had to close my browser and restart it. but why was I getting this type of captcha in the first place?

Comment: Those look like the captchas you'd get if you were in a different country (I get those when using Tor a lot)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Thanks. But I really think the rate at which these captchas are appearing for me is too much. I have answered at least 5 captchas today on different SE sites

Comment: Apart from on [data.se] (which is only because I'm not logged in), I doubt I've seen a captcha more than once on [se], ever (although my memory has been known to suck). At what rate are you attempting to answer questions? Or what else are you doing that [se] deems you suspicious?

Comment: Assuming that the poster is to blame seems a bit... unhelpful and... well, judgemental.  Maybe it's original author's own fault, and maybe it isn't.  If you're seeking additional information from the original author, I think it'd be more friendly to ask your questions without presuming that it's the original author's own fault for doing something suspicious or dodgy.  Just because you haven't seen difficult CAPTCHAs doesn't mean that everyone who does see difficult CAPTCHAs has done something suspicious or wrong.

Comment: @Dukeling Rate on SO low, Rate on Pets beta quite high

Comment: @D.W. I haven't seen any (except the first), not difficult, nor easy, and I do occasionally answer questions in quick succession. And doing something suspicious doesn't mean doing something wrong - it could be perfectly acceptable to have a high answer rate.

Comment: @Dukeling, I understand, but I'm saying that your experience does not imply that if someone sees a difficult CAPTCHA, they've necessarily done something suspicious. The factors that determine the difficulty of CAPTCHA aren't public. It could be based upon factors that aren't under the control of the original author or don't relate to his/her behavior (e.g., country, user agent, IP address, or any of a number of other factors).  To me, your comment came off as slightly accusatory; if that wasn't your intent, then maybe it could have been worded a bit more carefully.

Comment: PS information on why you're getting a captcha at all: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81086/165455 If you search here on captcha you should also find some other things about why you might be getting it more often than you should...