# CAPTCHA impossible to solve due to device limitations

Tags: bug, mobile-web, captcha

I just got challenged on programmers. The CAPTCHA is **impossible** to solve because my device (iPhone + Chrome using mobile site) **can not copy the text** required to be copied and pasted into the input field!

Best effort to copy text:

[image: copy fail]

But after clicking "Copy", the clipboard is empty: Trying to paste never gave me an action option. The way to be shown an option was to type something in, select it, then long-press, but with the clipboard empty, "Paste" was not an option:

[image: paste fail]

You'll notice too that when searching in-page for a character in the target, there are no hits highlighted.

---

Further, I have *never* been able to solve the "street signs" image challenge (I got through to the copy-paste on a food image challenge).

Example of failed "street sign" challenge:

[image: street sign challenge fail]

And a failed food challenge:

[image: food challenge fail]

Please tell me where I went wrong; I'm pretty sure I checked the correct images.

For comparison, here's the food challenge I passed:

[image: food challenge success]

This is getting a little silly.

Comment: oops, wrong dupe. Though pretty sure there was one..

Comment: [Nice try, robot.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81012/please-stop-asking-me-a-captcha-with-over-500-reputation-i-am-human/81017#81017)

Comment: @AdamDavis elsewhere on the net... a writing prompt [Bob doesn't realise he's a robot until he fails a captcha five times in a row...](https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/3glqfn/wp_bob_doesnt_realise_hes_a_robot_until_he_fails/).  Hmm.  Bob. Bobemian. Bohemian. I wonder...

Comment: Hm, am I a robot? Can I turing test myself?

Comment: @Steven yes, you are a robot. We are all wet-ware robots.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same copy-pasting problem on my tablet, except it did allow me to paste, but it messed up all the spacing and formatting.

I was able to fix this by reset of the device to factory settings, then it worked and let me sign in from the beginning normally.