# Getting Captcha Frequently

Tags: discussion, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Captcha Bypass](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46671/captcha-bypass)
>   [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

I am getting captcha's frequently. After one or two answers given, if I try to post an answer or edit an answer, I am getting a captcha.

Also I am getting unreadable captcha's in which half words are cropped. E.g. See below image : 
[image: captch image]

Any way to avoid it?

Comment: no it's not I checked and I dont know whether it works or not by taking it `back`.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8041

Comment: Also related: [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2167)

Comment: And last but not least: [I am not a robot!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143455)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters ! Well I know purpose of captcha, but I am facing this problem right now.

Comment: @Nandkumar: We all are :-) Hence the large number of posts on the subject.

Comment: also I am getting unreadable captch in which half words are cropped.

Comment: You guys will S#!t bricks if you see [this!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/impossible-captcha-with-non-keyboard-characters) LOL :D

Answer (score 0):

I've recently seen such question and i came to know that, **you don't have to answer such questions. It is a trick to identify bots. If you are able to type those complex characters or symbols,you are not recognized as a human coz we can't type such characters easily!** And the best solution to counter this is **Re-captcha** ;)

Comment: These capcthas are based on recaptcha and are a mix of real distorted words/letters and scanned input. Most likely the invalid characters are from a document tha couldn't be OCR'd. In any case, only one half is actually used to determine if you're human and the other half is to help them improve OCR/identify invalid text. It used to be that the easy-to-read part was the actual test but over the last year or so, the "real" text has become more and more garbled, possibly in part due to anonymous claiming they'd broken recapcha (they hadn't but they had realised you only needed to enter half)

Comment: @Basic Thanks for your information :)