# Hard to type captcha code

Tags: support, captcha

While I was submitting a question I got this captcha code:

[image]

I don't know how to type that, my keyboard doesn't have a pi key.

Comment: `atto urrsur`? It is a captcha...

Comment: @Ben how did you know its tt its looks like even very like to py

Comment: I don't know; it's a guess (there's a question mark). Did you try though?

Comment: yes but ... not working .....

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be Greek? We have seen words in Russian, Greek, and Hebrew before. Might work if you have that kind of keyboard. :-) Otherwise, try another captcha.

Comment: At least pi was readable.  I've seen some when 3/4ths of the letters in the captcha were partially out of frame and impossible to read.  I always just ask for another until I get one that is readable and has all Latin characters.

Comment: I am human so I found it from internet(at least I searched). Robots can't research. Capital pi `Π` and Small pi `π`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Impossible Captcha with non-keyboard characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/impossible-captcha-with-non-keyboard-characters)

Comment: To all those complaining about the words presented here, the issue is that this is recaptcha, and not "Stack Overflow Captcha" and not "Stack Exchange Captcha". You're likely not even familiar with the reCaptcha system, so you should read up on it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48840/impossible-captcha-with-non-keyboard-characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not only pi, apparently the three characters are Greek ([alpha](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b1/index.htm), [pi](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c0/index.htm), [omicron](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3bf/index.htm)). You actually have to enter `απο`, as typing `a` and `o` instead of `α` and `ο` will probably not work.

Now, for the actual typing, it depends on your platform:

- On Windows, provided you have the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method!EnableHexNumpad` registry value set to `1`, you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, type <kbd>+</kbd> (on the numeric keypad), then <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> again, type <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> one last time, type <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- On Linux, it's a little easier (at least with GTK-based browsers): You have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>.

As you can see, it is not trivial, and a lot of effort just to solve one captcha. There is no shame in requesting another, as hammar suggests, if you're short on time or find this exercise a little futile.

*Futile Update:* In light of psubsee2003's comment, I'm not so sure about that omicron now. All references to `απο` (["from" in Greek](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CF%80%CF%8C)) that I can find around have a tonic accent on the omicron (`από`), which means the final character is probably [Greek Small Letter Omicron With Tonos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3cc/index.htm) (`U+03CC`). Not trivial indeed.

Comment: On OS X, if you have the Unicode hex input enabled, hold Option and press 03B103C003BF. Otherwise, open the character viewer (Edit > Special Characters…) and search by name. Except for pi, that's option+P (US layout).

Answer (score 15):

In these cases you can always ask for a new CAPTCHA by pressing the "refresh" button.

[image: press the top button to get a new CAPTCHA]

Comment: this is not the answer?

Comment: @user177258 This is not an answer. But this is the best and fastest solution of the problem!

Comment: The issue is that this is recaptcha, and not "Stack Overflow Captcha" and not "Stack Exchange Captcha". You're likely not even familiar with the reCaptcha system, so until you want to learn about how it works, quit whining that this isn't an answer.