# Did the anti-bot algorithm thresholds get tightened?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The reCAPTCHA has become too difficult for humans to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve)
>   [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

Just wondering because those captchas are starting to get on my nerves and I don't recall there being that many in the past. I do not particularly enjoy being trolled by the site for improving questions via quick and small edits.

Comment: Ha, so I'm not the only one? They do seem to have gotten far more frequent these last few days.

Comment: Yep, me too. Seems like something got tweaked a little.

Comment: I've definitely noticed an increase in the number of captchas in the past two weeks or so.

Comment: If you would stop editing those "discount shoes" links in, maybe the captchas would relax a bit.

Comment: Surely Discount Gucci Handbags are just fine....

Comment: @jonsca Discount shoes? Was not _dishes_? Uhmmm… This is the second time I misread something I read. Is it time I change my eyeglasses?

Comment: @kiamlaluno So, yes ;)

Comment: Stop using bots to edit questions for you and you'll likely see less captchas.

Comment: <insert obligatory "nice try, robot" comment here>

Comment: Have you been using the new review feature?  I've noticed this, too, but only when I'm reviewing posts — a process that allows me to view/edit/flag a lot more posts in a shorter period of time.

Comment: @BradMace: Closely related, but not a dupe, since the primary issue here is not the difficulty of the CAPTCHA itself, but the frequency with which it's hit.