# Is it just me or the Captcha increased in frequency?

Tags: feature-request, bug, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)

Since recently I've noticed that the Captcha increased in frequency on SO (I am using only SO and cannot speak about other SE sites). While behind my corporate proxy at work this was understandable and was happening often before as well => multiple users coming from the same IP, etc...

But at home I am also seeing it appear more often than my patience could bear. It's starting to really harm my productivity and become annoying to the point of a PITA. I am accustomed to performing multiple edits to my answers after I post them and the Captcha literary hits me after the second or third edit to my answer and it wasn't like that in the past.

Has some policy changed?

I would understand if some policy changed and for some reasons the Captcha had to appear more often than before and would accept that (if a reasonable argument is brought here of course), but at least make this Captcha text more readable. I am like staring and clicking on the refresh button a couple of times before I get some exploitable text out of the image. I feel like I have to solve some puzzles instead of helping people with their programming related questions.

Comment: Yeah, this was recently discussed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot

Comment: How about changing your answering behavior?

Comment: Yes, and the captchas [have once again become very hard to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve/).

Comment: @nhahtdh, no, this is absolutely out of the question and that's not what I asked about here.

Comment: @nhahtdh that is not a solution.

Comment: I've received CAPTCHAs when *editing* posts. I'm definitely not keen on changing my editing behavior just to accommodate them. I have things to edit.

Comment: From [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143460/186964), people with 10k+ has 10 seconds window instead of 30 second window between edits. I'm not sure what compels you to submit edit within time frame of 10 seconds.

Comment: @nhahtdh, it's a habit that I absolutely do not intend to change. I prefer not to discuss my habits here. And my edits often come in a less than 10 seconds frame. It's how I use the site, alright? So do you know the answer to what I am asking about here: `has some policy changed`?

Comment: @nhahtdh Just because you don't bump into this or work slower doesn't mean this is not a bother to others. And constantly having to fill out a captcha is enough to turn you off. I'm not sure I would run into the 10sec window, but certainly do run into the 30sec window.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Are your concerns addressed by the first link I posted and can we consider this a dupe? Or do you have something new to discuss? (See the answer by Balpha on "policy")

Comment: @Bart, lemme read the dupe link.

Comment: @Bart: I agree with you about 30 second window. +1

Comment: @Bart, no I am not satisfied with the dupe link's answer. It says that it is fixed, but this still harms me, so for me this is not fixed.

Comment: perhaps update your question here then to reflect how this is not a dupe. Now it reads as one and might be closed as such. (Ah, there you go...)

Comment: Anyway, getting back to answering non-subjective questions on SO as from what I can see Meta is a waste of time. Sorry for having wasted yours.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Balpha said in the comments on his answer that we're looking at fixing the fix, as it were. I unfortunately don't have an ETA on it.