# Increase captcha threshold for post editing for 5k users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, edits, captcha

The captcha threshold has been [reduced already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing):

> Some reductions in CAPTCHA throttle
>   thresholds, if you have > 10k rep:
>
> - for edits -- reduced by two-thirds
> - for post submission times -- min seconds reduced by one half, max
>     minutes increased by 2x

I propose however to make this change available at 5000 instead of 10000.

In my opinion, a user with 5000 proved already that he is not a bot, and also, it would be something to give to people who are "halfway there" to the 10k.

Comment: *and seriously, with focusing more on editing/closing than answering, that's probably the only way I would see this change in less than a year time*

Comment: While I don't particularly mind the CAPTCHA no matter how many times it slams me in the face, I wouldn't mind something nice to bridge the gap between 3k and 10k, and this is something that seems quite appropriate. You've got my vote.

Comment: 10k is not a large amount of rep. Is it?

Comment: @Mehrdad, Yes, it is quite a bit. Haha, how's the weather up there?

Comment: Related: [Look again at increasing the captcha threshold for post editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/look-again-at-increasing-the-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing) (actually a duplicate, but with a limit probably too easy to reach)

Comment: As a user with ~5500 rep, I approve of this feature request. :)

Comment: Whether 10K is large is pretty site-relative. On SU/SF it's pretty much while on SO it's relatively easy to hit it in a month or two (if you post nice answers). +1 regardless, 5K is a fair limit.

Comment: The point isn't whether 10K is large. That's very subjective. People on the first page of SO users think it's small. Most users think it's large. The real issue is how much reputation is required to determine that you are probably a real person. 5000 seems more than sufficient, IMO.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Well, rep can just prove that you probably *have been* a real person, not that you *are* a real person (there's a correlation though) but accounts can get hijacked and the more accounts having this lower rate limit, the higher probability that a bot can get through stuff. It's the raw number of accounts that matter here. That said, I support this proposal and have already +1'ed.

Comment: Is this really necessary? It makes posting on SO much more annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.