# Reduce Captcha threshold for high rep users

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Captcha for higher rep users even necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/why-is-captcha-for-higher-rep-users-even-necessary) 
>   [Increase captcha threshold for post editing for 5k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users)

It happens when I want to edit the question a little bit better, but if I edit already, and have to edit within the next 10 seconds or half a minute, then it will "Captcha" me, probably thinking I can be doing spam?

If somebody has been a user for 1.5 years and never have a record of a spam, as reported by other members, then is it quite confident that the user is not entering spam?

Also, if when I enter a brand new question, it doesn't "Captcha" me, then why if I am editing, then it "Captcha" me, because if I were to enter spam, I could have entered it in the brand new question, no need to "edit it".

Comment: Oh, *please* implement this request!

Comment: For "high rep" meaning >=10k there [already are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing/8036#8036) reduced captchas.