# When does captcha stop on SO?

Tags: discussion, captcha

I'm wondering when at what threshold it stops. I know I don't have a lot or reps but I don't remember seeing a captcha after my first day. The other day I had to fill a captcha to post a new question. *Filling it out is not a problem*, but I'm just wondering if there is a threshold or do the guys with 200k reps see them once in a while.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't stop.  The expectation is that without it someone could spoof/steal/phish a high rep user's account and post thousands of spammy messages in a few seconds without it. I wouldn't be *too* surprised if they turned it off for certain high volume users that expressed personal annoyance.  It interferes specifically with my posting style.

Comment: They do already display the captcha less for higher rep users.  I'm not sure what the numbers are though.

Comment: @Justin Drastic reduction at 10k - documentation cites it as "reduced by 2/3 for post edits, and by 1/2 for post submission". In practice, well, I haven't had a single CAPTCHA since hitting 10k despite not changing from an earlier, CAPTCHA-filled action pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The rate at which are you asked to fill out a CAPTCHA is reduced as your reputation increases, but you are still asked.

[Increase captcha threshold for post editing for 5k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users)

Comment: To be accurate, it's not a gradual process but two separate privileges. At 200 reputation, you receive a 5 minute grace window that prevents you from getting a CAPTCHA if you had just gotten one. At 10,000 reputation, the actual rate at which you can trigger the CAPTCHA is drastically reduced.