# Add captcha threshold information to privileges page

Tags: feature-request, privileges, captcha, privileges-page

**Related:** [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)

**Related:** [Increase captcha threshold for post editing for 5k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users)

The captcha often gets to me when I'm editing a lot of posts in rapid succession. I was wondering if at some point you can get enough reputation to not have it interrupt you as much, so I looked on the SO [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges). However, I didn't see anything there about captcha privileges. Then I dug up the related threads above, which indicate that indeed there *are* reputation levels at which you can reduce captcha interruption. Why not include this information in the list of benefits on the [10k moderator privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)?

Comment: +1, that's definitely annoying!

Comment: I got them too since a week or two for quick edits. And I have slightly more than 10K... (http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc). So whatever those old questions mentioned about supposed "threshold", something has most certainly **changed** in the last few week.

Comment: Oh, that's what changed: a broken fix: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot/143460#143460