# Feature Request: relaxed spam rules for established users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, captcha, rate-limiting, spam-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)

It would be nice to have slightly relaxed spam rules for established users. In my experience (on SO), all it takes for me to see Bret and Jermaine is a couple of fast edits even though I've got a 3.5k+ reputation. Of course it's not like it happens often, but when it does, it feels like an unnecessary bother. So here's my suggestion: relax the spam detection a little, reserved for established users with 2k+ or 3k+ reputation. Not so much that it would allow a compromised account to have a free spam buffet (or is it really a buffet when you're bringing the spam?) but just enough that it becomes nearly impossible for a normal user to trigger the spam detection.

Sorry for the block of text :)

Comment: It is already relaxed for higher rep users, though as usual I can't find the reference.

Comment: Jeff highlights the current relaxation in his answer at: [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing). You can also check out related requests like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53575/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing-for-5k-users) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/look-again-at-increasing-the-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing).