# Avoid robot check for a given reputation level?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)
>   [Look again at increasing the captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/look-again-at-increasing-the-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)

While 1K rep is not really high, I would think that it would be sufficient to avoid the robot checks on StackOverflow.

Privileges does not seem to have any mention of robot checks.

I don't mind it too much, but on the other hand I really see no reason why I should be robot-checked.

Answer (score 11):

Captcha checks are never eliminated, in case a spammer gains control of your account; even moderators get captcha checks if they do things too quickly. They are suppressed for 5 minutes after completing one if you have at least [200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69004/145982), and reduced quite a bit when you hit [10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8036/145982), but they never go away