# Reduced "Am I human?" checking for high rep users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase captcha threshold for post editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2167/increase-captcha-threshold-for-post-editing)

Often I find myself confronted with the feared "Human Verification" page when I'm doing silly admin tasks on SO like removing flamebait, or more recently removing the `teenage` tag on SO.  Can people with higher rep get a little more leeway for fast typing?