# Provide the option to hide funny CAPTCHA images

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I'm at work, and I work in one of those "open concept" offices.  I'm the only IT person in here.  I really don't want people to think I'm watching Flight of the Conchords when I'm just trying to edit a question a few times.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58917/best-way-to-minimize-captcha-interruption

Comment: Use the [Dillo browser](http://www.dillo.org/)? :P

Comment: It's a cute image, but SO is supposed to be geared towards professionals. It might be just a tad too cute.

Comment: I think the Adblock answer that someone posted but apparently deleted upon the first downvote, was not a bad workaround. If the workspace is that strict, then [some ads might be troublesome as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51736/ads-that-contains-erotic-images)? (Ah, the answer is back!)

Comment: As usual a Greasemonkey or Stylish script will work... (but I can't work on it because I need to see the actual code, and I have no idea how to trigger that thing). I suppose if I give a dummy answer then quickly edit it five to six times I will see the thing?

Comment: Applying reductio ad absurdum, you're the only one that does what you do, your co-workers don't have a clue, they don't appreciate what you do, they automatically assume you are goofing off when they see an unusual image on your monitor.  How is that SO's problem?

Comment: @YiJiang, see http://stackoverflow.com/captcha ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/), you can right-click on it and select **block image**.

Comment: I really never liked this answer. A. It's not an ad. B. I have to install third-party software and C. I always relate it to this. If I told a client this for one of our applications, they'd probably flip.

Comment: I'm running ad-block (not adblock plus, because I'm on chrome). I don't see a bunch of ads, but this image isn't one. I've installed a variety of plugins to my browser like "switchImages" that turn off images, but then I can't see the damn captcha graphic :(

Comment: You have to block it specifically. I don't know how you do that in Chrome's ad-blocker.

Comment: Adblock now supports this under chrome6. Accepting because it solves my problem, but I'd doubt that SO wants us blocking their ad space.

Comment: @user142287: I haven't used Chrome's ad-blocker, but at least with Adblock Plus, actual ads are only blocked if you subscribe to a filter for them.