# onEdit check delta of revisions before captcha

Tags: feature-request

Related to:

[Best way to minimize captcha interruption](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58917/best-way-to-minimize-captcha-interruption)

[Provide the option to hide funny CAPTCHA images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/provide-the-option-to-hide-funny-captcha-images)

The issue that happens when we edit posts rapidly, normally I would suspect are minor changes. Right now, the check looks like it's checking just the *speed* at which changes are being made, but not considering the *weight* of them.

A small edit (lets say 5% of the text), shouldn't contribute as massively to the trigger as, lets say, a 90% change. Keep the speed, but weight the average of changes made.